# How can I set the yAxis scale for the chart?

Tags: chart.js

I need to set the yAxis scale so that it would start from zero to 100 with the intervals of 10. I tried several options with the scales but it didn't seem to work. I also tried to set 
options: { scales: { yAxes: [{ ticks: { beginAtZero:true } }] } } });

but this didn't help, I still have negative numbers at the yAxis scale. How can I solve it?

```
    var MONTHS = ["Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"];
    var config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ["Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Продажи",
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
                borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
                data: [
                    10,
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor()
                ],
                fill: false,
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            title:{
                display:true,
                text:'Показатели роста продаж'
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'index',
                intersect: false,
            },
            hover: {
                mode: 'nearest',
                intersect: true
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Месяц'
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Рост'
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    };

    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-0").getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `ticks` property of `yAxes` options. Refer the below code or fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/Lzo5g01n/10/

Always make sure you reference the latest version of Chart.js library.

```
yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Рост'
        },
        ticks:{
            min: 0,
          max: 100,
          beginAtZero: true, 
          stepSize: 5
        }
      }]
```

Comment: It works fine, thank you very much! However, the chart line itselа still can have negative numbers when I randomize the data, as you see: http://like.alexanz3.beget.tech/chart1            
Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @AlexandraMeas There is some problem with the link you posted. My internet doesn't allow me to access it. Try some other hosts, please.

Comment: Sorry, now it is fixed and will open